# Only apply NSSortDescriptor to entities filtered by NSPredicate for a NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

For a TableViewController, I am creating an NSFetchedResultsController.

Model looks like: EntityA <---->> EntityB. In the code below, the relationship is called entityRelationship. EntityB has an NSNumber attribute called attribute.

I need to filter and sort the results. I do it like so:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entityRelationship.@count > 0"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"entityRelationship.@avg.attribute"
                                             ascending:NO];
```

Basically, I need to display all entities that have a non-empty entityRelationship and sort them by the average of attribute of entityB.

The code shown throws the exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Isn't sortDescriptor only applied to results filter by the predicate? How could I achieve this in one request? (Since this request is linked to a NSFetchedResultsController, I don't want to first fetch and then sort).

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Based on Duncan's answer, I was able to find a solution. I still find it pertinent to post my answer, with the same example as in my question.

In a category based on EntityB, I overrode the setter of the attribute. (I need to know the average of all attributes within EntityA to sort them). Here's the code:

```
- (void)setAttribute:(NSNumber *)attribute
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"attribute"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:attribute forKey:@"attribute"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"attribute"];

    EntityA *entityA = self.entityA;
    float mean = 0;
    int nbItems = 0;
    for (EntityB *b in entityA.entityB)
    {
        mean += [b.attribute floatValue];
        nbItems++;
    }
    [entityA setAvgAttribute:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(mean/nbItems)]];

}
```

This way, each time I set the attribute in EntityB, the average is re-calculated, which is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Is the exception thrown on the first line of code or the last line?

Comment: It is thrown when executing the fetch, at the fetch line: 
`_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest                  managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
sectionNameKeyPath:nil
cacheName:nil];
`

Comment: Of course, duh (me I mean).  I get the following exception when trying to sort based on the number of children indicating use of KVC aggregates is not allowed.  Not surprising because you can't specify a keyPath only a key.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle children.@count'

Comment: An easy way would be to create a persistent property and keep that updated with the average value of the children's property.

Comment: Sounds promising. I guess that overriding the setter of the attribute that affects this avg in a category for that entity (EntityB in the example) would do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to create a persistent property and keep that updated with the average value of the children's property.

Here is an example of setting the status on a project node (NSManagedObject subclass) based on the status of its children, note that in this case both the parent and the children are of the same class.  Calculating the average of an attribute value of the children should be straight forward, but let me know and I can post a modified version to illustrate:

```
- (void) setStatus:(NSNumber *)status
{
    //LOG(@"setStatus called");
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"status"];
    [self setPrimitiveStatus:status];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"status"];

    if (self.parent !=nil)
        [self.parent updateStatus];

}

- (void)updateStatus
{
    // Do nothing if we are on hold
    if ([self.status intValue] == 5)
        return;

    // Ignore if user has set SpecialGroup on it
    if ([self.isSpecialGroup boolValue])
        return;

    self.status = [self getMyStatus];

}
- (NSNumber*)getMyStatus
{
    NSMutableArray *statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (ProjectNode *child in self.children) {

        // Ignore on Holds.
        if ([self.status intValue] != 5)
            [statusArray addObject:child.status];
    }

    // Check is all are 0
    int result = 0;
    BOOL isOneBehind = NO;
    BOOL isOneNotStarted = NO;
    BOOL isOneStarted = NO;
    BOOL isOneCompletedLate = NO;
    BOOL isOneCompleted = NO;

    for (NSNumber *status in statusArray) {
        int v =[status intValue];
        if (v == 0)
            isOneNotStarted = YES;
        if (v == 1)
            isOneStarted = YES;
        if (v == 2)
            isOneBehind = YES;
        if (v == 3)
            isOneCompleted = YES;
        if (v == 4)
            isOneCompletedLate = YES;

        if (v != 5)
            result = MAX(v, result);
    }
    if (isOneBehind)
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    if (isOneStarted)
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    if (isOneNotStarted) {
        if (isOneCompletedLate)
            return [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];
        else
            if (isOneCompleted)
                return [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
            else
                return [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }
    if (isOneCompletedLate)
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];

    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:result];
}
```

Comment: As soon as I can implement this I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: I accepted your answer because of the strategy you suggested. But I will also post my own answer because it is closer to the example I gave in my question. Thank you!